# Show p:confirmDialog with p:selectBooleanButton

Tags: user-interface, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to show `p:confirmDialog` with `p:selectBooleanButton` follwoing is the code with `p:commandButton` it works fine but not with `p:selectBooleanButton`

```
<p:commandButton value="#{confirm.message}" icon="#{confirm.image}" actionListener="#{confirm.handleChange()}" update="messages">  
        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />  
    </p:commandButton>  
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">  
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>  
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>       
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

when I put `p:confirmDialog` tag with in `p:selectBooleanButton` whole page is not visible.
here is my code

```
<p:selectBooleanButton value="false" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" onIcon="ui-icon-check" offIcon="ui-icon-close">  
            <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:selectBooleanButton>
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">  
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>  
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>       
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: I guess its because onclick event is not available in selectBooleanButton. In generated html javascript for p:confirm is added to onclick event of p:commandButton in first case.

Comment: p:selectBooleanButton is not confirmable. You can add confirm box

Comment: The thing is not possible because, the `p:confirmDialog`'s interface is not implemented by `p:selectBooleanButton` and it throws un registered behavior exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectBooleanButton is not confirmable. The other option is to use as

```
<h:body>
        <h:form id="form">

            <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{testBeanTwo.selectedOption}" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" 
                onIcon="ui-icon-check" offIcon="ui-icon-close">
                <p:ajax listener="#{testBeanTwo.showDialog}" />
            </p:selectBooleanButton>

        </h:form>
        <p:dialog id="test" widgetVar="testW" dynamic="true" modal="true" draggable="false">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                <f:facet name="header">  
                Are you sure ?  
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandButton value="Yes"></p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton value="No"></p:commandButton>
            </p:panelGrid>


        </p:dialog>


    </h:body>
```

And in your managed bean

```
private boolean selectedOption;

    public BeanClass() {

    }

    public void showDialog() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (selectedOption) {
            context.execute("testW.show()");
        } else {
            context.execute("testW.hide()");
        }

    }

    public boolean isSelectedOption() {
        return selectedOption;
    }

    public void setSelectedOption(boolean selectedOption) {
        this.selectedOption = selectedOption;
    }
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks Makky, useful as alternate